# Css: Add style to last element with class (without js)

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

I have a problem with create css (sass) selector, which select last element with class in list (**WITHOUT JAVASCRIPT**):

```
<ul>
  <li class="post pinned">1</li>
  <li class="post pinned">2</li>
  <li class="post">3</li>
  <li class="post">4</li>
</ul>
```

Need to select last post with pinned class (i.e. 2).

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54narkq7/1/)

Comment: :last-child, :last-of-type not worked

Comment: There is no `nth-of-class` selector..you need javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

In fact `:last-child` don't work because it only selects the last child of the container no matter what class it has, and `last-of-type` don't work because it only selects the last element with a specific type from your container.

**Alternative:**

So basically the best solution is to use a dedicated class for such element:

```css
.micropost {} .micropost.pinned {
  color: red;
}
.micropost:last-child {
  color: green;
}
.lastPinned {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="micropost pinned">1</li>
  <li class="micropost pinned lastPinned">2</li>
  <li class="micropost">3</li>
  <li class="micropost">4</li>
  <li class="micropost">5</li>
  <li class="micropost">6</li>
  <li class="micropost">7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Need last micropost with pinned class (i.e. 2)

Comment: Yes @Satif indeed this isn't possible with css only (take a look at my answer), you need to use javascript or jquery.